# How can I output an XML file of a sale in Magento?

Tags: xml, magento

I'm trying to tie two systems together and need to create an XML file of an order once a sale has gone through. It would need to include basic customer details (name, address), order details (products ordered, discount codes used) and transaction details (payment reference).

What would be the best way of creating this XML file? What would I need to create and where?

Comment: Once you create your xml file, how does the other system access it (ftp, email etc)?

Comment: Effectively, FTP. It's a batch process job that reads the XML files from a particular folder and then sends the message to delete on retrieval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an observer for `sales_order_place_after` that generate and save your xml files

```
<events>
    <sales_order_place_after>
        <observers>
            <feed_sales_order_observer>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>feed/order_observer</class>
                <method>export_new_order</method>
            </feed_sales_order_observer>
        </observers>
    </sales_order_place_after>
</events>
```

See [Customize Magento using Event/Observer](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method)

Comment: According to the site: 
Note for recent versions of Magento - Broken
Seems like this tutorial doesn’t work anymore for recent versions (1.6.2 for me), because of magento prices indexing. Price is not calculated on the fly on frontend anymore, and indexing does not call the event “catalog_product_get_final_price”. To be confirmed.

Comment: That was just a reference on how to create a observer, and will not affect what your doing